# "disagrees about version" message

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, kgdb

I get a message "disagrees about version" on boot time, after compiling **kernel and modules** with KGDB. Why should this happen ? Is there any problem with KGDB ?

This is the relevant log at boot:

```
udevd-work[125]: error changing net interface name eth0 to eth1: Device or resource busy
tlc59108: disagrees about version of symbol backlight_device_unregister
tlc59108: Unknown symbol backlight_device_unregister (err -22)
Starting Bootlog daemon: ipv6: disagrees about version of symbol page_address
ipv6: Unknown symbol page_address (err -22)
ipv6: disagrees about version of symbol page_address
Applying sync command
```

Comment: This messages means that the kernel and modules were compiled separately and from sources or configurations that were not identical. Are you absolutely completely sure that you compiled the kernel and the modules together and that you installed the correct versions?

Comment: Hi Gilles, Yes I'm sure. I compiled it with the following sequence:  1. removed moduless from filesystem 2. make clean 3. make uImage 4. make modules 5. make modules_install. I suspect that maybe KGDB from GIT is failing and that I need patch for my version (2.6.37) ?

Comment: If you only executed these steps, then you didn't boot from the new image, since you never installed it (you only installed the modules).